# Get data from one dataframe to another according to a column in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe looks like this

```
df1
          x           y             Classification
    1   567610  5934630                0
    2   567630  5934630                0
    3   567530  5934610                0
    4   567492.7 5934585               0
    5   567493.3 5934585               0
    6   567492.3 5934584               0
    7   567492.8 5934584               0
    8   567590 5934610                 0
```

And another one

```
df2
     x       y     V1   
1  567610 5934630 16.153   
2  567630 5934630 20.450   
3  567530 5934610  1.175
```

Expected output

```
df2
        x       y     V1      classification
    1  567610 5934630 16.153     0
    2  567630 5934630 20.450     0
    3  567530 5934610  1.175     0
```

I tired this but its not working

```
df2 %>% 
  rows_patch(semi_join(df1,df2, by = "x"))

Error in `semi_join()`:
! Input columns in `y` must be unique.
✖ Problem with `x`, `y`, and `V1`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I want to compare the x and y in both the dataframe and if they match each other then get the classification to the df2. All of the x and y of df2 is from df1 so all of them will match. i just need the classification from df1 to df2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `left_join` instead of `rows_patch` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
  left_join(semi_join(df1,df2, by = "x"))
#> Joining with `by = join_by(x, y)`
#>        x       y     V1 Classification
#> 1 567610 5934630 16.153              0
#> 2 567630 5934630 20.450              0
#> 3 567530 5934610  1.175              0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Its still giving me the same error

Answer (score 0):

**using `dplyr`**

```
library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c("x", "y"))
```

**using `data.table`**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

df2[df1, on = c("x", "y"), nomatch = 0]
```

**results**

```
        x       y     V1 Classification
1: 567610 5934630 16.153              0
2: 567630 5934630 20.450              0
3: 567530 5934610  1.175              0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could connect both columns between your two `dfs`:

```
left_join(df2, df1, by=c('x'='x', 'y'='y'))
       x       y     V1 Classification
1 567610 5934630 16.153              0
2 567630 5934630 20.450              0
3 567530 5934610  1.175              0
```